# Hyperlink to open File in Eclipse Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hyperlink

I am creating an Eclipse plugin. I have embedded the Eclipse internal browser into an Eclipse view. I wish to add a hyperlink to the webpage that is displayed in that view to open a file in the Eclipse CEditor. Can this be done and if so how? Thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this snippet for a way to call Java code from JavaScript in the browser: [Snippet 307](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java)

The next step is to add an `onClick` handler to the link which calls the JavaScript. There are plenty of examples how to do that.

In Java, you can then tell Eclipse to open the file in an editor (ask a new question if you don't know how to do it).

[More SWT browser snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/).

Comment: Thank you Aaron for the quick response. That is exactly what I needed.